# Explanation for Partial Diagonalization of a Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, invariant-subspace

Just to note, I haven't yet studied Jordan Normal Form or similar. I am working through a question that contains the following:

Say we have
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Its only eigenvalue is $1$ with eigenvector $v_1=(1,1,1)^T$, so it is not diagonalisable. Also the subspace $X=\{(x,y,z)^T:x+y+z=0\}$ is 2-dimensional, with basis $\{x_1,x_2\}$, and is $A$-invariant.

Why is it the case then that if we define
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
|&|&|\\
v_1&x_1&x_2\\
|&|&|
\end{pmatrix}$$
we have
$$P^{-1}AP=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\0&a&b\\0&c&d
\end{pmatrix},$$
without the need to complete any calculation? It is clear that the first column would be $(1,0,0)^T$ but I do not see how to rigorously determine that the top row must have the two zeroes.

Comment: have you done any work here?  I would suggest starting with the case that $v_1$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are mutually orthonormal.  The product is an orthogonal matrix which gives the result.

Comment: The solution simply states: " For the matrix to have the required form, we must also have that the second and third
columns of P are basis vectors for a 2-dimensional invariant subspace" so I have a feeling that the justification should come more simply

Comment: what's simple depends on what you know.  I assume this is over $\mathbb R$.  A very simple approach is to define subspace $W:= \big\{\alpha \mathbf 1\big\}$ and $W^\perp$.  Since the ones vector is an eigenvector of $A$ it is immediate that $W$ is $A$-invariant.  Now show the same for $W^\perp$ i.e. $AW^\perp \subseteq W^\perp$ and apply this insight to $AP = BP$.  You see $B$ must have said form because these subspaces are $A$-invariant.  You should be able to fill in the details.

Comment: * should say: apply this insight to $AP=PB$